# Download string from bitbucket with basic authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, webclient, basic-authentication

I am trying to make some bitbucket api requests using csharp.bitbucket library.  I have some code which fetches a request token then builds up an authenticate url. The authenticate url looks something like

```
https://bitbucket.org/api/1.0/oauth/authenticate/?oauth_token=xxxxxx
```

Where xxxxx is my token that I have already retrieved via bitbucket api.

The issue I am having is when I try to using webclient download the url I always get the bitbucket login page even though I am passing an authorisation header.  When i hit the authenticate url using postman and pass through the same token and authorisation header it all works.  My code looks like this:

```
                using (var wc = new CookieWebClient(_username, _password))
            {
                pageText = wc.DownloadString(url);
            }
```

The CookieWebClient class looks like

```
public class CookieWebClient : WebClient
{

    public CookieContainer m_container = new CookieContainer();
    public WebProxy proxy = null;        

    public CookieWebClient(string authenticationUser,string authenticationPassword)
    {                                 

        string credentials = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(authenticationUser + ":" + authenticationPassword));

        Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = "Basic " + credentials;

    }

    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
    {
        try
        {
            ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 1000000;
            WebRequest request = base.GetWebRequest(address);

            request.Proxy = proxy;

            var webRequest = request as HttpWebRequest;
            webRequest.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent] = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36";
            webRequest.PreAuthenticate = true;
            webRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
            webRequest.Pipelined = true;
            webRequest.KeepAlive = true;

            if (webRequest != null)
            {
                webRequest.CookieContainer = m_container;
            }

            return webRequest;
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

It looks like the authenticate part via webclient is not working becuase when i make the DownloadString call I get the bitbucket login page.

Anyone seen this before?

Thanks in advance

Ismail

Comment: Bit more information on this when running with post man it hits /api/1.0/oauth/authenticate/?oauth_token= then does 301 redirect to /site/oauth1/authorize?oauth_token= the authorisation header is maintained however with webclient after the 301 the header is lost.

Answer (score 1):

So in answer to my own question, after looking at fiddler and postman I could see that when calling authenticate it was doing a 301 redirect and losing the authorisation header so I updated my code to hit the url it was trying to 301 to.

So instead of authenticate i goto authorise directly while passing my token and authorisation header and now it all works.  This all used to work however I think at bitbucket's end they have changed something hence the breakage.

So issue is 301 redirect losing authorisation header that has been set.  Hope this helps someone.

Ismail